# How split factory_girl definitions across many files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

My `factories.rb` file became too big to maintain over time and I'm now trying to split it across many files in `factories` directory. The problem is that I don't know how to deal with dependencies.

To make a long story short, I'm trying to split my factories in following way. All sequences go to `sequences.rb` file and each factory definition goes to separate file like so:

**factories/sequences.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   sequence :name {|n| "Name #{n}" }
   sequence :email {|n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
end
```

**factories/user.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        name
        email
    end
end
```

**factories/post.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :post do
        name
        content "Post Content"
        user
    end
end
```

When I run tests I get `name` is not defined error. I can deal with this by passing a block to each association (e.g. `name`, `email`, `user` and so on) mention but it seems to be ugly and not DRY.

1. Is there way to let `factory_girl` know sequence in which files should be loaded?
2. to deal with complex dependencies when it's not possible to fix this issue with changing load sequence of files?

Comment: would the [Faker Gem](https://github.com/stympy/faker) be an alternative to those sequences? I find them ugly to be honest...

Comment: As @TheCha͢mp indicates use [FFaker gem](https://github.com/ffaker/ffaker) or something similar (Forgery) for this. it is a solved problem IMO, I've gone down the route of sequences and that way lies madness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply achieve the result with `generate` method:

```
# factories/sequences.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
end

# factories/user.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email { generate(:email) }
    password '12345678'
  end
end
```

Then try it:

```
FactoryGirl.create :user
=> #<User:0x007fa99d2ace40
 id: 1,
 email: "person1@example.com",
 . . .>
```

[Sequences Documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Sequences) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I do this in this way:

1. Create separate folder for shared factories. It should in same level as 'factories' folder.

> factories
>
> shared_factories

2. Create shared file, ex. `shared_factories/sequences.rb`
3. Import `sequences.rb` to every factory file.
   `require_relative '../shared_factories/sequences'`

The full example:

https://gist.github.com/alexkojin/6a2d70f84ff91c37315d1d3edb0d8e6b

Comment: FactoryGirl doesn't allow put shared resources in `factories` folder. It will raise `DuplicationError`.

Answer (score -3):

You can do this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        sequence(:name) {|n| "Name #{n}" }
        sequence(:email) {|n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
    end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :post do
        content "Post Content"
        user { create :user }
    end
end
```

There are a variety of ways to structure your factory girls factories such as traits, inheritance, callbacks, etc. I just recently learned about traits and it is really wonderful:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        sequence(:name) {|n| "Name #{n}" }
        sequence(:email) {|n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
    end

    trait :with_post do
        after(:create) { |user| create :post, user: user }
    end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :post do
        content "Post Content"
        user { create :user }
    end
end

# and in your specs you will do this:
let!(:blogger) { create :user, :with_post }
```

It is very worthwhile to invest some time reading through the entire documentation (a 30 mins read perhaps?). Thereafter, you will have much better ideas to refactor your factories.

Reference link: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: The question is clearly about how to split up all the factories across different files.